# How do I center an element when possible without overlapping the sidebar?

Tags: css, flexbox, grid-layout

Here's what I want to achieve. There's a red sidebar on the left, width fixed with `160px`. Meanwhile I want to keep the blue box in the center of the page if possible, with the maximum width of `240px`.

But when there's no enough space, I do not want the blue box to overlap the red box, so the blue box doesn't have to be centered anymore (figure 3).

When there's even less room, the blue box should be shrinked to fit in the available space (figure 4).

[image]

I'm trying to use `position: absolute` on the red box but it causes overlapping. Any suggestions?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

side {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: salmon;
  flex: 0 0 160px;
  justify-self: start;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

main {
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: steelblue;
  flex: 0 1 240px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <side></side>
  <main></main>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use grid layout

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  }

  side {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: salmon;
  }

  main {
    width: 240px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: steelblue;
  }
```

```html
<section>
  <side></side>
  <main></main>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a margin on an appropriate media query:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

side {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: salmon;
  flex: 0 0 160px;
  justify-self: start;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

main {
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: steelblue;
  flex: 0 1 240px;

  @media screen and (width < 560px) {
    margin-inline: 160px auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <side></side>
  <main></main>
</section>
```